# Unable to find document with specified parameters in MongoDb using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find document match with specified ObjectId and post but in result it is alway returning available even if document is not present there.

This is my code below:

```
router.post('/check',(req,res) => {

   MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true},(err,client) => {

            var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
            var uId = { _id:new ObjectId(req.body.uId)};
            var pId = req.body.pId;

            if(err){

                console.log("Error" +err);

            }else{

               var collect = client.db('Example').collection('Wishlist');

               collect.find({_id:uId,postId:pId},(err,doc) => {

                            if(err){

                            console.log("Error" +err);

                            }if(doc){

                              res.send("Available");

                            }else{

                              res.send("Not available");
                              client.close();
                           }    
                 });   
            }  

      });

});
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have middleware that transforms `req.body.pId` to an integer and that it's not a string value in your database, then your query will fail to find anything. `123 !== "123"`, after all. The query `{_id:uId,postId:pId}` is currently searching for for an `ObjectId` and a `string`.

Cast the value from the user's input to an integer:

`var pId = parseInt(req.body.pId, 10);`

Now the query `{_id:uId,postId:pId}` will search for an `ObjectId` and an `integer`.

---

Another thing that looks odd is that you have your `_id` value in an object. While that is possible in MongoDb, should it not be the following?

`var uId = new ObjectId(req.body.uId);`

Comment: Here pId is a String and not an Integer.

Comment: I want to check if both fields are present in a document.

Comment: Then you need to add more information to your original question. It's too vague right now. What do your documents actually look like?